# Visual bug in GDM for Arch Linux

Tags: linux, gnome, arch-linux, gdm

Whenever I boot into GDM, I get this weird visual tearing of the elements on the screen. I'm able to actually log in (by pressing enter and typing in my password) but the visual elements in the login screen are completely messed up. I have `gnome` and `gnome-extras` installed and I've updated my system with `pacman -Syu`. I checked the journals and nothing of interest seems to be there either. I also have my proper display drivers installed for my system.

Any thoughts on how to fix GDM? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The login screen uses Wayland by default – it could be that your video driver only works properly in Xorg for some reason. Try editing `/etc/gdm/custom.conf`:

```
[daemon]
WaylandEnable=false
```

Comment: This worked! No idea why gnome would default to wayland, I've personally never seen it used!

Comment: **Well, you just did.** GNOME defaults to Wayland for the login screen because they have been [_moving towards Wayland_](https://blogs.gnome.org/mclasen/2016/01/22/a-wayland-status-update-2/) since at least GNOME 3.14, as have many other desktop interfaces (e.g. KDE and Enlightenment). As the login screen is rather limited (no windows at all, no Xwayland) it was switched in 3.16, most people didn't notice. (There's a gear-menu selection to use Wayland for your own session as well.)